# Глючит AdMob в Unity приложении на android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, admob, google-play-services

Написал игру на Unity. Подключил google play services, и настроил сохранение на облако. Все работает нормально. Осталось подключить рекламу, выбрал плагин от AdMob. Установил и написал по инструкции с оф. сайта код:

```
public class AdMob : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AdMobConfig _config;
    private BannerView _bannerView;
    private RewardedAd _rewardedAd;

    public bool IsRewardedAdLoaded => _rewardedAd == null ? false : _rewardedAd.IsLoaded();

    private void Start()
    {
        //FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().OnGameRestart += HandleGameRestart;
        InitializeAll();
    }

    public void TryShowRewardedAd(Action rewardSucessfulEarnedCallback)
    {
        if (IsRewardedAdLoaded)
        {
            _rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += (object sender, Reward r) => rewardSucessfulEarnedCallback();
            _rewardedAd.Show();
        }
    }

    public void InitializeAll()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });

        RequestRewardedAd();

        if (CloudStorage.Variables.ADS == true) 
            RequestBannerAd();
    }

    private void HandleGameRestart()
    {
        if (_bannerView != null)
        {
            _bannerView.Destroy();
            _bannerView.Hide();
        }
    }

    private AdRequest GetRequestBuild()
    {
        return new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    }

    private void RequestBannerAd()
    {
        _bannerView = new BannerView(_config.BANNER_ID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        _bannerView.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleBannerAdLeavingApplication;
        _bannerView.LoadAd(GetRequestBuild());
    }

    private void HandleBannerAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _bannerView.Destroy();
    }

    private void RequestRewardedAd()
    {
        _rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(_config.REWARDED_ID);
        _rewardedAd.OnAdClosed += (object sender, EventArgs e) => RequestRewardedAd();
        _rewardedAd.LoadAd(GetRequestBuild());
    }
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Config", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/AdMob/Config")]
public class AdMobConfig : ScriptableObject
{
    public string BANNER_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    public string INTERSTITIAL_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    public string REWARDED_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
}
```

В редакторе все работает нормально, все как мне надо. Скомпилировал, закинул на телефон(андроид). В игре есть музыка, которая играет на фоне. Когда сворачиваешь игру, то музыка продолжает играть и секунд через 6 замолкает. Почитал и выяснил, что вроде как проблема в том, что реклама не успевает выгрузить ресурсы из памяти и поэтому игра не сворачивается до конца.

**ПОМОГИТЕ Я УЖЕ УМИРАЮ, Я НЕ ЗНАЮ КАК ЭТО ФИКСИТЬ**

Comment: Не знаю поможет это здесь или нет, но попробуй про https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netcore-3.1 почитать

Comment: Вроде андроид хелпер про это что-то рассказывал. (При настройке сервисов гугл плей), они вроде конфликтуют между собой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Короче говоря, ошибка в том, что из другого компонента я каждый кадр(в методе Update) обращался к свойству класса AdMob IsRewardedAdLoaded, а он в свою очередь к методу _rewardedAd.IsLoaded(), и из-за этого на последнем кадре перед тем как игра полностью свернется идет задержка(возможно, выполняется запрос к какому-нибудь гугловскому API). И из-за этого игра не считается свернутой, как я понимаю, и музыка продолжает играть. Поэтому если есть такая же ошибка, то лучше используйте события RewardedAd для записи в какую-нибудь переменную.